# Printing the negative number's postion from array list

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I have been looking over and over this code and can't seem to figure out the answer. However, I know it is a simple solution, I just can't find it as of right now...

Basicly, what i'm trying to is find the postion to all the negative numbers from the array-list. (Positionorder: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) Then print which position the negative numbers have. When compiling the code Java tells me what the error is:

> Test.java:11: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='
>
> ```
> while (a<=0) {
>        ^
> ```
>
> first type:  int[]
> second type: int
> 1 error"**

But how can I resolve the problem, anyone who can guide me in the right direction and also an explanation of why `while (a < 0)` is not allowed in the current code. (The task is to do this with `while`)

```
String posNegative = 0;
int[] a = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};
while (a < 0) {
    posNegative++;
    System.out.println(posNegative);
}
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're trying to apply `<` to an `int[]`, which makes no sense. You're also incrementing `String`, which again, makes no sense.

Comment: Your code seems to suggest that you want your output to be one-based (ie, if the first element in the array is negative, you want to print 1).  The answer you've accepted gives a zero-based answer (ie, if the first element in the array is negative, it prints 0).  Be careful to understand that array indexes in Java start from zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. First of all, what you actually want for your problem is as simple as this:

```
int[] a = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] < 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Now let's look at your code. If you look at the error message it says that you are trying to compare an `int[]`, a, and an `int`, 0. An `int[]` is a completely different type than `int`, so they cannot be compared. Read `int[]` as "int-array".

There's also the issue of this line:

```
String posNegative = 0;
```

I'm guessing that what you are thinking is that you need `posNegative` to be a String so that you can print it. That, however, is not necessary. `System.out.println()` can take pretty much anything you throw at it. When you declare a number, declare it as

```
int posNegative = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is an array. An array cannot be less than zero.

You can iterate through the array either by putting

```
for (int item : a) {
    ...
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    item = a[i];
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the array with its contents. The array itself cannot be a negative integer, because it's an array, not an integer. To access the array's contents use a[n] where n is the index of the element you want to access.

```
int[] a = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};
for (int n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    if (a[n] < 0) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `posNegative` never changes. This would just print 0s

Comment: Wow, thanks. I didn't realize i was confusing the array with its contents.

Answer (score 0):

a is not an int, it is an array of ints. If your intent is to loop over an array, you can use an enhanced for loop:

```
for(int i : a)
{
    posNegative++;
    if(i < 0)
    {
        System.out.println(posNegative);
    }
}
```